# How can i get vertical space between li tag using CSS

Tags: css, html-lists

i would like to get vertical space in between each `<li>` tag  in one of my list items. I tried it using CSS Grid, but then i getting equal vertical space and has unnecessay extra space eventhough there is one line of sentence. Hopes anyone can help me to get a solution. Following is the code. Thanks in advance!

```css
html {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}   
a {color:#555;text-decoration:none;}
.container {padding: 1.5rem;background-color: #cdcdcd;margin: 1rem;/* width: 50%; *//* border: 1px solid red; */}

@media only screen and (min-width:567px) {
.container {padding:3rem;background: #f9f9f9;}    
}

.list {
    background: #fff;
}
.list__ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    column-count: 2;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.list__item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    break-inside: avoid-column;
}

.list__item:before {
    content: "";
    width: .10rem;
    height: .1rem;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: solid #555;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    margin-right: .75rem;
    margin-top: .25rem;
}
.list__link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="list">
        <ul class="list__ul">
            <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list1__link">One Precise control In addition to the ability to place items accurately onto a created grid, the CSS Grid Layout specification contains rules that control what happens.</a></li>
            <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list1__link">Two Default value One Precise control In addition to the ability to place items accurately onto a created grid, the CSS Grid Layout specification contains rules that control what happens</a></li>
            <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list1__link">Three Sequential navigation </a></li>
            <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list1__link">Four Algorithm specification</a></li>
            <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list1__link">Five Dynamic Sources</a></li>
            <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list1__link">Six Auto Placement</a></li>
            <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list1__link">Seven Task Allocation</a></li>
            <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list1__link">Eight Implicit Contents</a></li>
            <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list1__link">Nine Absolute Specification</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add padding to li element, if you want to isolate it only to this ul list then use something like:

```
.list__ul li {
     padding-top: 20px;
}
```

To skip the first li element:

```
.list__ul li:nth-child(1n+2) {
     padding-top: 20px;
}
```

In order to also have vertical space use padding-right or padding-left or try to use padding inside class element list__item.

Comment: Hello Aljaz, your code will make additional space in the top of the block. The content should be fit in the red outline and needs vertical space at the same time. This is the requirement. Thanks for your initiation!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `margin-bottom` of your desired space in `list__item` `class`.e.g. I am using `margin-bottom: 10px;`. This will solve your problem.

```
.list__item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    break-inside: avoid-column;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.list__item:last-child {
                margin-bottom: 0px;
            }
```

Comment: Hello ishtiaq, i tried this solution, but it will make an additional space after the last item. I  am trying to avoid space in between the red border and content. Hopes you understood. Thanks for initiation.

Comment: I just updated answer. You can just add `.list__item:last-child {margin-bottom: 0px; }` to avoid that extra space

Comment: But this code only focusing the last child of 2nd column, not the last item of first column.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an after pseudo element to the ul element you can set its height to be the height of the ul minus the padding given to each li.

Then set the border on this pseudo element rather than on the ul.

If it is important that the ul takes only the space it looks as though it's taking then set its bottom margin to minus the padding given to each li.

```css
html {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  margin: 1rem;
  /* width: 50%; */
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}

@media only screen and (min-width:567px) {
  .container {
    padding: 3rem;
    background: #f9f9f9;
  }
}

.list {
  background: #fff;
}

.list__ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: -20px;
  margin: 0;
  column-count: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.list__ul::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  left: -1px;
  top: -1px;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.list__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.list__item:before {
  content: "";
  width: .10rem;
  height: .1rem;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid #555;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin-right: .75rem;
  margin-top: .25rem;
}

.list__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list">
    <ul class="list__ul">
      <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list1__link">One Precise control In addition to the ability to place items accurately onto a created grid, the CSS Grid Layout specification contains rules that control what happens.</a></li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list1__link">Two Default value One Precise control In addition to the ability to place items accurately onto a created grid, the CSS Grid Layout specification contains rules that control what happens</a></li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list1__link">Three Sequential navigation </a></li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list1__link">Four Algorithm specification</a></li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list1__link">Five Dynamic Sources</a></li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list1__link">Six Auto Placement</a></li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list1__link">Seven Task Allocation</a></li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list1__link">Eight Implicit Contents</a></li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list1__link">Nine Absolute Specification</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```